# How to pull link text into a Bootstrap Popover?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

If I have a link that fires a Bootstrap Popover, how do I pull the text from within the link into the popover content?

Using `$(this).text()` seems not to work.

So given the HTML:

```
<a href="#">Get this text into the popover.</a>
```

And this JQuery:

```
$('a').popover({
    content: $(this).text()
});
```

I want the popover content to be "Get this text into the popover."

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to popover content to be a attribute/value of the element, then use the `content` property as a function that returns the value as shown below

```
$('a').popover({
    content: function(){
        return $(this).text()
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lcu4n/)